# JavaFX/Netbeans Program Not Running

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

This is my code that I have so far in my Netbeans program. It is supposed to bring up a window with a picture in it, the picture being called seawave. But for some reason it is not running. Do you have any idea why?

```
    package myseaapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class MySeaApp extends Application {

    private ImageView seawave;
    private Rectangle seawaveClip;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

       seawave = new ImageView(new Image(MySeaApp.class.getResourceAsStream("images/seawave")));
       seawaveClip = new Rectangle(300, 220);
       seawaveClip.setArcHeight(20);
       seawaveClip.setArcWidth(20);

       seawave.setClip(seawaveClip);
       Pane root = new Pane();
       root.getChildren().add(seawave);

       Scene myScene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
       myScene.setFill(null);
       primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and this is what I get...

```
Executing /Users/SethRataiczak/NetBeansProjects/MySeaApp/dist/run1104410607/MySeaApp.jar using platform /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1110)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:694)
    at myseaapp.MySeaApp.start(MySeaApp.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application myseaapp.MySeaApp
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory /Users/SethRataiczak/NetBeansProjects/MySeaApp/dist/run1104410607
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I just updated my post to show what I get when I run my program

Comment: The error message means it cannot find the image resource.  It should be at myseaapp/images/seawave

Comment: Also, since you are running from a jar file, make sure the image is bundled in the jar file.

Comment: I added the myseaapp at the beginning and i am still getting the same thing...how would i make sure the image is bundled in the jar file?

Comment: From the command line you can do `jar tf MySeaApp.jar`. (See the first line of the output for the location of the jar file.)

Comment: this is what i got....`java.io.FileNotFoundException: MySeaApp.jar (No such file or directory)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:120)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1115)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:293)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)`

Comment: Are you in the same directory as the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

First of All use try and catch block for error handling like this

```
try {
 // code 
}catch {
 // error handling code
}
```

and second you did not use your image type example .png, .jpg etc

```
seawave = new ImageView(new Image(MySeaApp.class.getResourceAsStream("images/seawave")));
```

change this line of code with correct image type

Like this:

```
seawave = new ImageView(new Image(MySeaApp.class.getResourceAsStream("images/seawave.jpg")));
```

Comment: I added the .jpg and I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: Is your image in .jpg format ?? Check its format and add to the end. Otherwise you can't stop getting `java.lang.NullPointerException.`

Comment: it's not necessary that image is .jpg it can be .png, .svg etc as well check image properties